# How to render table without id using Angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using material in Angular project from this example:
https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

I have table with data set:
  `displayedColumns = ['userId', 'userName', 'progress', 'color'];`
For render I am using code:

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <div class="example-header">
    <mat-form-field floatPlaceholder="never">
      <input matInput #filter placeholder="Filter users">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
          The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

    <!-- ID Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="userId">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Progress Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="progress">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Progress </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.progress}}% </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="userName">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Color Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="color">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Color </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [style.color]="row.color"> {{row.color}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

I dont want to render ID Column, *but* I want id variable in array.

How can I disable rendering of id column? When I remove code:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="userId">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

I am getting error:

```
ERROR Error: cdk-table: Could not find column with id "userId".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you have not removed the "userId" from the list of displayed Columns,
In your template

```
 <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```

Here the value displayedColumns is being initialized in the component (the corresponding *.ts file).
Which might look like

```
displayedColumns = ['userId', 'userName', 'progress', 'color'];
```

Just remove the 'userId' from the above list and it will work.

Comment: Keep the definition, 
------------
 <!-- ID Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="userId">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
_________________
Only remove from the list of displayedColumns